# Detecting when a method is chained

Tags: ruby

I am looking to do some method chaining. I have the following code:

```
class MyClass

  attr_accessor :handler

  def do_a
    puts 'i just did a'
    self.handler = 'a'
    self
  end

  def do_b_if_a
    puts 'i just did b' if handler == 'a'
  end

 end
```

So the following works:

```
irb > test = MyClass.new
=> #<MyClass:0x007fa44ced9a70 @handler=nil>
irb > test.do_a
'i just did a'
irb > test.do_a.do_b_if_a
'i just did a'
'i just did b'
```

What I DONT want to work is when I call do_a the first time it sets the handler, which means now do_b_if_a can be called at any time. But I only want it to be called when it is chained with do_a, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're tracking state in the wrong place. You'd be better off with something similar to ActiveRecord's query interface, for example:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :handler

  def do_a
    puts 'i just did a'
    with_handler 'a'
  end

  def do_b_if_a
    puts 'i just did b' if handler == 'a'
  end

private

  def with_handler(h)
    o = dup
    o.handler = h
    o
  end

end
```

That way you always have an instance of MyClass but you have a throw-away copy that keeps track of its history. This is similar to [cHao's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319403/chao) approach but it doesn't need an extra decorator class as MyClass can decorate itself.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you don't want to care (and in most cases, you don't even get to *know*) if your methods are called in a certain way.  That way lies madness.  Magic call sequences make for a hell of a time debugging and testing.

What you could do, though...instead of having `do_a` return `self`, wrap a decorator around it that defines `do_b`, and return the decorator.  At that point, your original `MyClass` can't `do_b`, cause it doesn't know how. But the thingie returned from `do_a` can.

(Now, you can still say like `a = test.do_a` and then `a.do_b`, but you can't really get around that without parsing the Ruby code yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

As cHao said, you shouldn't try to method call patterns. But I can also think of another way to do this:

```
def do_a
  puts "i just did a"
  do_b_if_a(true)
end

def do_b_if_a(did_a=false)
  puts "i just did b" if did_a
end

do_a       # prints "i just did a"
do_b_if_a  # does nothing
```

Sure, you *can* call `do_b_if_a(true)`, but then it just makes it more flexible ;)

Comment: The problem is I still need to have access to the object.

Comment: What do you mean, access to the object?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't get you all the way there, but you could define `do_b_if_a` as a singleton method that gets added when `to_a` is called:

```
class MyClass

  def do_a
    puts 'i just did a'
    self.tap{|s| def s.do_b_if_a; puts 'i just did b' end}
  end

 end
```

You could take a look at [Kernel.caller](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) if you want to take certain actions based on the call stack.  However, you might get punched in the face by another developer if you don't have a good reason for doing so, lol.